# French radio or tv programs about the French language?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage, télévision, radio

I've just started to learn French and as I'm very interested in language in general, in my mother tongue, I listen to radio programs and watch tv series about this language. I'm thinking that I would benefit a lot from also listening to and watching programs about the French language, in French. They usually bring up subjects that aren't easily captured by dictionaries: different accents, neologisms, new types of constructions and so on.

So, my question is: What are some French radio or tv programs that deal with the French language (I'm mostly interested in French as it's spoken in France)?

Comment: [Karambolage](http://www.arte.tv/karambolage‎) on Arte TV is about both french and german cultures and languages.

Answer (score 2):

There is a short radio program on "France Inter" which is called "qu'est-ce que tu me jactes". Each week, this radio program explains a French argot term.
So you can download the podcast and listen to it, you will learn something in each program, it's quite interesting. I am French, and I learn something each time I listen to it.
You can download it [here](http://www.franceinter.fr/emission-quest-cque-tu-mjactes).

Answer (score 1):

I found the game show “Mot de Passe” (on France 2, Saturday evening) a good TV programme for Intermediate level students of French language who may want to augment their 'contextual vocabulary'.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few radio podcasts are available on tunein.com (or the tunein smartphone app!):

http://tunein.com/search/?query=learn%20french

Comment: But I'm not really interested in french lesson podcasts as such. I'm looking for something like what this site does actually, but in tv or radio format. Questions on best practice, how the language is developing, about different accents, neologisms, slang and so on. These programs would not be for learners of the French language, they would be for the French people. [A Way with Words](http://www.waywordradio.org/) seems to be like what I'm looking for, but in English and about English.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to watch the international tv [TV5Monde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV5Monde). It's a global television network who is brodcasted in over 200 country and territory.